# Alternative d3.format that correctly rounds numbers?

Tags: d3.js, rounding

Is there an alternative to d3.format that is based on Math.round rather than Number.toFixed?

I love d3.format but it doesn't round 0.05 as one would expect via scientific or other rounding conventions (see https://github.com/d3/d3-format/issues/27)

Currently d3.format uses `Number.toFixed` rather than `Math.round` internally, which results in unexpected rounding https://github.com/d3/d3-format/issues/89

So sometimes 0.05 rounds down (`8.95=>8.9`) , and sometimes it rounds up (`2.95=>3.0`) but it doesn't follow a standard scientific rule like 'round to even' but based on the binary representation

```
[0.95,1.95,2.95,3.95,4.95,5.95,6.95,7.95,8.95,9.95]
returns
 ['0.9', '1.9', '3.0', '4.0', '5.0', '6.0', '7.0', '8.0', '8.9', '9.9']
```

because

```
[0.95,1.95,2.95,3.95,4.95,5.95,6.95,7.95,8.95,9.95].map(v=>v.toFixed(16))
returns
0: "0.9500000000000000"
1: "1.9500000000000000"
2: "2.9500000000000002"
3: "3.9500000000000002"
4: "4.9500000000000002"
5: "5.9500000000000002"
6: "6.9500000000000002"
7: "7.9500000000000002"
8: "8.9499999999999993"
9: "9.9499999999999993"
```

I love the incredible expressive flexibility of the d3.format specifier syntax.  I realize there is an argument to be made to round based on the binary representation.  But it gets hard convincing business users that `$8.995` is really `$8.9949999999999992` and so technically should round down to `$8.99` while $8.595 is really 8.5950000000000006 and should round up.

**Goal** My practical goal is to swap out d3.format entirely in our applications, so that code we've written that depends on d3, and auxiliary libraries we import such as Plotly.js and others which use d3 display numbers rounded as we all learned in elementary school rather than as a few of us learned in grad school. E.g.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.js" </script>
<script src="https://some.other.size/libs/altd3.format.js"></script>
<script> d3.format = altd3.format </script>
```

Comment: d3 does round 0.05 correctly; the issue is that `v+0.95` introduces floating point error before `Math.round` (or anything) can act. `9.9499999999999993` is indeed less than `9.95`.

Comment: @BallpointBen. This happens even with direct inputs, E.g. `d3.format('0.1f')(8.95)` returns `"8.9"` whereas I believe it should round to `"9.0"`.   For instance, `(Math.round(8.95*10)/10).toFixed(1)` returns `"9.0"`

Comment: I revised the example to list the input values directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const round = (num, digits) => {
  const multiplier = Math.pow(10, digits);
  const value = Math.round(num * multiplier) / multiplier;
  return value.toFixed(digits);
}

console.log(round(3.14159265359, 3));
console.log(round(2.7182818284, 2));
```

**Update**

Here is a modified function rounding the last digit to `0` or `5`:

```
const round = (num, digits) => {
  const multiplier = Math.pow(10, digits) * 2;
  const value = Math.round(num * multiplier) / multiplier;
  return value.toFixed(digits + 1);
}

// round(0.993212345, 2) = 0.995
// round(0.991234567, 2) = 0.990
```

Comment: This does rounds 8.95 to 9.0 as I'd expect, equivalent to how I'd expect `d3.format(".1f")` to work. But there is a huge set of possible format strings a user might specify, e.g. `["$.1f", "$.2f", ".2%",  ".1f", ",.1f", ".1s", ".^20", ...]` (see https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-format?collection=@d3/d3-format)  and all of them will have weird edge cases where fractions ending with digit 5 don't round as expected.  My question is whether there is a variation of d3.format that parses the d3 format syntax but rounds the 0.xx5's as a business or science consumer would expect?

Comment: @prototype see my updated unser

Comment: Aha, I failed to write the use case.  My goal is not just to round numbers where we control the code, but to get other libraries like Plotly.js that use d3.format to convert numbers to display strings also round as end users might expect.

Comment: @prototype I suggest you to post a new question about to the problem with a third-party library, but I don't think it's possible at all.